# MySQL query though PHP not returning values

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I'm building a simple log-in function for a site, and I've come across some trouble. When I try to log in to the site, I keep getting the error that username and password doesn't match. This is of course an error I've defined myself, but the problem is that I shouldn't get it in this case.

I printed the calculated hash for the password, and made sure that this step was properly performed, which it was. After this, I ran

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE user='username' AND pass='hashed_password';
```

directly toward my MySQL database, supplying the username and hash directly. This returned the desired values. My PHP code looks like this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db";
$u = "localhost";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,$u);
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user=':username' AND pass=':hashed_pass'");
$query->execute(array(':username'=>$username,':hashed_pass'=>$hashed_pass));
$result = $query->fetch();
if($result){
    //Log in user
}else{
    //Print error
}
```

This does not return anything, even though I supply the correct values, it keeps giving me the error. I'm not sure what might cause the problem, but if I'd make a guess I'd say that it has to do with the charsets. My database uses **UTF-8**. Although, I still got the desired results from MySQL when querying the database directly though SSH with **ISO-8859** encoding.. So I'm really not sure. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where do $username and $hashed_pass come from and are you sure they contain correct values? Use echo to confirm this.

Comment: This is totally unrelated but You're better off selecting the user with a username then matching the password of the resulting user table with the hashed password with php.

Comment: @CreativityKills Not sure I agree with this.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse it's safer and makes more sense. Select row with username, compare the password with inputted password using if && ===  it's more flexible and extendible.

Comment: @CreativityKills Could you explain why that would make if safer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing quotes. PDO does NOT replace given parameters if they are wrapped in quotationmarks.

Example:

```
$st = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users ( name, surname ) VALUES( :name, ":surname" )');
$st->execute( array( ':name' => 'John', ':surname' => 'Carlo' ) );
```

Results:

-> John, :surname

You can also use `debugDumpParams` to see the parameters are either correct or not. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php